# О вводном слове «во всяком случае»

Tags: вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

У Розенталя приводится пример, где сочетание ***во всяком случае*** является обстоятельством и не обособляется: …***Во всяком случае** он никогда не оставит прежнего своего питомца* (П.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Пример показался мне неубедительным,  и я решила **проверить пушкинский текст**: *«Наконец государь написал ему, что он неволить его не намерен, что предоставляет его доброй воле возвратиться в Россию или остаться во Франции, но что, **во всяком случае**, он никогда не оставит прежнего своего питомца».*
https://rvb.ru/pushkin/01text/08history/03memoires/1152.htm

Там был использован обособленный вариант И стало непонятно: **зачем изменен текст оригинала?**

Что вы об этом думаете, **насколько удачен пример**?  Можно определить обстоятельственное значение ***во всяком случае***  в этом  предложении без контекста?

Спасибо.

Comment: А мне вот стало интересно: на сайте old-rozental.ru представлен действительный справочник Розенталя? Какие у нас есть гарантии, что он не отредактирован не совсем компетентными людьми?

Comment: У меня есть двухтомник 2005 года, текст полностью совпадает с тем, что на сайте. Розенталь умер в 1994 году. В 1962 г. создал на факультете журналистики МГУ кафедру практической стилистики русского языка. Здесь он проработал до 1986 года, а профессором-консультантом оставался на этой кафедре до конца жизни. Но сложно сказать, насколько активно он занимался правописанием.

Comment: Мне кажется, что его самая известная книга - это  Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке. Для работников печати. — М.: Книга, 1967. (5 изданий). В 1994 году его сразу стали править (перерабатывать, обновлять и улучшать, как они сами указывают) В Интернете я прочитала такую запись: Хотя справочники  продолжают публиковаться в наши дни, нужно иметь в виду: автор умер в 1994 году. Издания, вышедшие после его смерти, имеют некоторые изменения, внесённые другими авторами, поэтому авторитетность таких изданий можно поставить под сомнение.

Comment: Уже не раз замечал, что Розенталь редактировал примеры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь "во всяком случае" не вводное выражение, поскольку имеет *конкретный* смысл "**и в том, и в другом [названном] случае**" (при подстановке запятые оказываются *явно* лишними). Но даже без этого контекста просматривается смысл "в любой ситуации". "Оригинал" условен: если нет рукописи, надо сопоставлять разные издания с разными корректорами. В сети я вижу только варианты текста без обособления и Розенталя понимаю: это совсем не то употребление, что в ситуации "не знаю, чем дело кончилось, во всяком случае, ничего хорошего быть не могло".

Возможно, такая манера речи сейчас устарела, поскольку выражение примелькалось в качестве штампа и непроизвольно воспринимается как вводное. Что-то похожее происходит в последние десятилетия с выражением "в том числе": развивается массовое непонимание его *буквального* смысла и сложившейся грамматической функции.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, я потом догадалась, что это обстоятельство, когда внимательно прочитала текст. Обстоятельство обособлено, и мне это понятно. Мы имеем право обособить его, если хотим как-то подчеркнуть. Здесь прямое значение сочетания, можно в текст подставить "при любых обстоятельствах", тогда обособление будет казаться более обоснованным. Но если не будет контеста, то  в начале предложения обычно ставится вводное слово, попробуйте здесь сделать замену, предложение будет выглядеть странно.

Comment: Поэтому этот пример мне  сразу не понравился. А вы бы без контекста посчитали бы его обстоятельством или вводным словом?

Comment: Без контекста (и не перечитывая на предмет грамматики) я принял бы его за вводное слово, поскольку в современной речи буквальный смысл ему обычно не придают.

Comment: Я тоже приняла бы его за вводное слово, в том числе по его позиции. Сравнить:  Своего питомца  он не оставит во всяком случае.  Но тогда все равно нужен контекст, где эти случаи перечисляются. В общем, неудачный пример, надо его убрать.  Раньше Нацкорпуса не было, вот и тяжело было с примерами.